# phpmysql Inverted index search match at least n words out of m words

Tags: php, mysql, regex

Search criteria

**1)** "Top group" that contain all keywords.

**2)** "Second group" contain all keywords except one.

… and so on until the apps that do not contain any keywords are shown.

Now I am able to get the Top group(point : 1). After that I have got stuck, so many combination need to be done on later steps. So, please help me to get a quick and proper method for my search.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`FULLTEXT` index, then use the relevance value from `MATCH`.  It won't give you *exactly* what you specified, but it will order the hits, which I assume is what you really want.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I was used FULLTEXT  for my first step. However I am now able to solve it using FULLTEXT and will post the resolutions here shortly.